# How to invert a radius in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have a Radius border in the text widget and I don't know how to "invert" the borderRadius so that it's not white:

[image: img]

I would like that the blue section and the green section stay together with the corners with radius.

```
Container( 
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_hPad, 10.0, _hPad, _hPad), 
  child: Text(_body), 
  width: appWidth / 2, 
  height: middleSectionHeight, 
  decoration: BoxDecoration( 
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only( 
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(70.0), 
      topLeft: Radius.circular(70.0), 
    ), 
    color: Color(0xff99AAAB), 
  ), 
),
```

Comment: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_hPad, 10.0, _hPad, _hPad),
          child: Text(_body),
          width: appWidth / 2,
          height: middleSectionHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(70.0),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(70.0),
            ),
            color: Color(0xff99AAAB),
          ),
        ),

Comment: Please add a picture of what you want to achieve

Comment: Kindly add any clarification to your Question with an edit. Also, I do not understand what "stay together with the corners with radius" means.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the BorderRadius as an argument:

The example class:

```
class ExampleContainer extends StatelessWidget {

  final String text;
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;
  final Color color;

  static const double _hPad = 10.0;

  const ExampleContainer(
      {@required this.text, @required this.borderRadius, @required this.color,});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_hPad, 10.0, _hPad, _hPad),
      child: Text(text),
      width: appWidth / 2,    //change to the width you want
      height: middleSectionHeight,    //change to the height you want
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: borderRadius,    //passing here the borderRadius
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Utilization:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ExampleContainer(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(70.0)),
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          text: 'title',
        ),
        ExampleContainer(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(70.0)),
          color: Color(0xff99AAAB),
          text: 'something2',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```